# How can i request for a class attribute extending the User Class in django

Tags: python, django, database, file, orm

I always get this Error

DoesNotExist at /file/new/1
StaffUser matching query does not exist.

My models.py

```
    class StaffUser(User):
        department = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

My Views.py

```
    def FileUploadForm(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        folder = Folder.objects.get(id=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            u = StaffUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
            form.instance.fileuser = u
            form.instance.folder = folder
            form.instance.department = u.department
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'File Successfully uploaded to {folder}!')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    
    return render(request, "pages/fileup_form.html", {'form': form, 'pk':pk})
```

I want to get the department of the user and add to the database

Comment: Have you configures Django to use StaffUser as your [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)?

Comment: pass username value you are passing user object change `u = StaffUser.objects.get(username=request.user)` with `u = StaffUser.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`

Comment: I've passed the username value but i still get the same error

Comment: I've tried to configure django to use the custom user model but it gives signup error because in my signup form, i added the department field in the form.
It doesn't allow for makemigrations.
and it usually brings a lot of errors.

I've tried to debug but i couldn't

Comment: Error means that you don't have data in `StaffUser` with provided username. Have you checked if data exists?

Comment: It shows user object has no attribute department

Comment: @DanielAzubuine it means you don't have any department linked with User